# Registration Verification for Android App

Tags: java, android, registration, android-2.2-froyo

I'm working on an app that requires users to register in order to use the features.

I need to ensure that users are who they say they are so I want to use some type of verification process, e.g. email or text verification.

The best solution would be to receive a text or email after registration with a code. This code can then be entered into the application to verify the login.

I know of GMailSender but that is as far as my knowledge would go for this type of situation.

I have no idea where to start with this and have researched a lot.

Any help would be great

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a server as part of the infrastructure for this app?

Comment: Yes, I am using a remote SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually entering a code received by email would be annoying for users and they are highly likely to abandon a process that forces this upon them. Also from experience, emails are so often caught in spam traps and not received.

You should make it as easy and non intrusive as possible.

e.g

Use the device's built in Google account to register with your server (after obtaining user permission of course).

On the server side perform the registration and return a code to the app.

Use the code returned by the server directly in the app to enable whatever features you see fit.

The above example would be a one click process and would require no manual code entry.